# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on LDAP login form

Tags: php

I want to make an LDAP login page to for some of my administrative tools on my website but ran into an issue after using a few templates I got.  I finally selected a template/tutorial that I thought would meet my needs, made the appropriate files and adjusted the variables, just to get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end error` after it was posted. I was just looking for some guidance for how I can make this project successful.

```
<?php
// http://sudobash.net/?p=736
session_start();
session_destroy();

if(!isset($_POST['user'])){?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
  <!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> -->
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<title>LOGIN TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center" height="200px" id="content">
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
          <h2>TITLE Login</h2>
          <form action="login.php" method="POST">
              <tt>RAC Username:</tt>
              <input type="text" name="user" size="30" /><br />
              <tt>RAC Password:</tt>
              <input type="password" name="password" size="30" />
              <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>

<?}?>

<?if(isset($_POST['user'])){?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
  <!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> -->
 <head>
  <title>LOGIN RESULTS TITLE</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

 </head>
  <body>
        <?php
        include 'conf.php';
        // Don't display the warnings - we are already setup to annoy the user
        ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
        // No funny stuff!
        $user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
        $user = explode(" ", $user);
        $user = $user[0];
        $user = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $user); 

        $filter = "admin=" . $user;

        // Connect to the LDAP server.
        $ldapconn = ldap_connect($server, $port) or
        die("Could not connect to " . $server . ":" . $port . ".");

        // Bind with rootreader to the LDAP server to search and retrieve DN.
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn) or die("Could not bind - contact admin@adamskalicky.com");
        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$basedn,$filter) or die ("Search error.");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
        $binddn = $entries[0]["dn"];

        // Bind again using the DN retrieved. If this bind is successful,
        // then the user has managed to authenticate.
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $binddn, $_POST['password']);
        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "<center><h2>Successful authentication for <span style='color: #000;'>" . $user . "</span></center>";
        ?>   <table align="center" height="200px" id="content">
             <tr>
               <td valign="middle">
                 <form action="restricted.php" method="post">
                   <input type="hidden" name='user' value="<?=$user;?>" >
                   <input type="submit" value="Great, Let's go!" >
                 </form>
               </td>
             </tr>
              </table>
        <?
        } else {
            echo "<center><h2>Failed authentication for <span style='color: #000;'>" . $user . "</span><br /><br />
                  <a href='login.php'>Try again</a></center>";
        }

        ldap_close($ldapconn);
        ?>

</body>
</html>
<?}?>
```

Comment: There is no apparent PHP error in the code you posted. There amy be one in the included file.

Comment: Remove the `<?}?>` from the end and add it after `ldap_close($ldapconn);` statement, like this: `ldap_close($ldapconn); } ?>`

Comment: @AmalMurali , I changed       


'ldap_close($ldapconn);
        ?>

</body>
</html>
<?}?>

TO

       ldap_close($ldapconn); } ?>

</body>
</html>'

but still get the same error.

Comment: @Sébastien the only included file is my conf.php file which only includes my server settings.

Just in case, here it is:
<?php
// Configuration file for PHP/LDAP authentication
$server = "68.64.160.18";  // YOUR ldap server IP
$port = 636;           // Default LDAP port when you are not root
$basedn = "ou=Users"; // Make sure to change to match your object.
?>

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause that error there either. Are you sure there is absolutely no other code included in your page? Can you try to write only the code you posted here in a standalone page and upload it to your server and see if it works?

Comment: @Sébastien: I was able to [reproduce](http://3v4l.org/3eGN1) this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed on http://3v4l.org/UaYh1 when you don't use PHP shorttags.
Can you try it on your own server?

Using shorttags is not a good thing anyway.